# Related Rates of Change rectangle

Tags: calculus

I am having some trouble on a related rates problem. The question is: given rectangle $ABCD$, sides $AD$ and $BC$ are $20$ inches long. Sides $AB$ and $CD$ are increasing at the rate of $3$ inches per minute. Find the rate of change in angle $CAD$ when side $CD$ is $15$ inches long.

I drew a picture of the problem, and attempted to solve it, but I'm not sure my answer is correct. I set $\tan{A} = \frac{15}{20}$ and differentiated. This results to $A'(\sec^2 A) 0.75$. Solving for $A'$, I got $0.5$ degrees per second. Does this answer make sense? I feel like there's a step missing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Jonny How is that relevant to the question? Angle CAD is not a right angle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let angle $CAD$ equal $\theta$. Let side $CD$ be $x$.

So $\displaystyle \tan \theta = \frac{x}{20}$.

Differentiating implicitly wrt time $t$,

$\displaystyle \sec^2 \theta \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{20}\frac{dx}{dt}$

$\displaystyle \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{\cos^2 \theta}{20}\frac{dx}{dt}$

Now use the right triangle $CAD$ to figure out the value of $\theta$ at the instant of interest.

$\displaystyle \tan \theta = \frac{15}{20} = \frac{3}{4}$

Hence $\displaystyle \cos \theta = \frac{4}{5}$.

So $\displaystyle \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{1}{20} (\frac{16}{25}) (3) = \frac{12}{125} rad/min = \frac{12}{125}\cdot \frac{180}{\pi} ^\circ/min = (\frac{432}{25\pi}) ^\circ/min \approx 5.5^\circ/min$.

The last part (conversion of radians to degrees) is optional. Remember that the natural unit for angle measure in calculus is the radian.